# How do I persist data in a QuestDB docker container?

Tags: questdb

I'm running QuestDB from the Docker image but when I stop it, the data is not persisted on restart:

```sh
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8812:8812 questdb/questdb
```

What's a good strategy for keeping the tables / records when restarting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways, a convenient way is to give the container a name when you start it first:

```sh
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8812:8812 --name questdb-example questdb/questdb
```

When this image is stopped, you can bring it up again with the data persisted:

```sh
# bring the container up
docker start questdb-example
# shut the container down
docker stop questdb-example
```